# how to check if input is number or alphabet in GNU bash

Tags: shell, carriage-return

I am getting error "If" and then"" unexpected in GNU sed command.How to check input continuously.Please help me

```
if ! [[ "$versionCode" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "Sorry integers only"
fi
```

This is my error

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")

sh: 1: Syntax error: "then" unexpected

Sorry integers only
sh: 1: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected
```

update:

```
echo "Enter version code" 
read versionCode
case "$versionCode" in
   (*[!0-9]*) echo "Sorry integers only";;
   ("")       echo "Empty is not a version code";;
   (*)        echo "do something with $versionCode";;
 esac
echo "$versionCode"
sudo  sed "s/\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)[0-9]*/\1${versionCode}/" Version.gradle
```

this is my error

```
Enter version code
4

sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected

sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected

sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected

sh: 1: Syntax error: "esac" unexpected
```

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry I did not understand please explain me

Comment: : I don't see any `sed` command in the code you have posted. Also, `[[ .... ]]` is not valid in POSIX shell.

Comment: Try this: `grep -q $'\r' your_script.sh && echo "carriage return found"`

Comment: Your code works in Linux Ubuntu, I can't test it in Win10 WSL.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIXly portable way to do this is

```
 case "$versionCode" in
   (*[!0-9]*) echo "Sorry integers only";;
   ("")       echo "Empty is not a version code";;
   (*)        echo "do something with $versionCode";;
 esac
```

Comment: @Manoj Yes it does work. If it does not for you, you are doing something wrong. Please be specific in what you have done with my script and what error message you get. "Does not work" is not a helpful description. What system are you on? Which editor are you using?

Comment: @jeans I am using GNU sed script and I update my script with error that i got and I am using ubuntu as windows sub system

Comment: @Manoj One problem could be the line endings on Windows (\r\n) versus Unix (just \n). Try the command Cyrus suggested above. Any output from that is a sign of line ending mismatch.